# Honor 6 missing OTA upgrade to android 6

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, ota-update, huawei-honor-6

I recently bought an Honor 6 (specifically the H60-L04 model) which I took from android 4.4 to 5.1 (firmware H60-L04C900B521) using the updater app, all went smoothly.

However, searching around, It would seem that android 6 update has been released in May as a downloadable firmware, and OTA update should have been out by June; yet, if I open the updater app, it says that my phone is already at last version.

So my question is threefold:

1. Is this because the OTA update isn't out yet, or because my phone is not compatible?
2. Is it safe to upgrade using the downloadable firmware? The procedure seems easy enough
3. Will such an upgrade reset my phone, or will it keep the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because the OTA update isn't out yet, or because my phone is not compatible?

Honor 6 user till few months ago. Honor 6 upgrades are a terrible mess:

- They are released region specific, example, India, Malaysia, Russia with the Chinese one completely different.
- Performance / Stability varies from region to region
- AFAIK except for Chinese, they're wasn't an OTA to start with. For Indian market the upgrade was available on their Facebook and then on their website and about two months later, OTA was released and that too had teething problems
- Company preferred mode of informing users is on their Facebook page , so you would need to check out there
- Downgrading is not straightforward and you have to risk that

So, coming to your specific question, it looks like OTA had not been released .

> Is it safe to upgrade using the downloadable firmware? The procedure seems easy enough

You can use update file but make sure you research user feedback because of downgrade issues. With the Indian version there were issues with battery life, missing functionalities, and random bootloops

> Will such an upgrade reset my phone, or will it keep the data?

If it is not OTA, you lose data

Comment: I deleted their Facebook page on the web browser and in in any case you would need to sign in first on their page to access. If you are happy with the present version, stick to it unless you are very sure that you want to upgrade after doing research. This is the main reason I sold my device

Comment: Thanks for all the info, it is indeed valuable! And to say I always heard that Huawei was a good brand...

Comment: Not for upgrades. It is a problem area. Best bet is to wait for OTA

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll wait for the OTA, if it is ever published.